# errors creating a custom web component with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to create a custom HTML5 web component in a Rails application, but I am getting errors instantiating the Javascript object.

**Version info:**
Rails 4.2.11.3
ruby 2.5.8
coffee-rails 4.1.1

I've reproduced the issue in a minimal Rails app, available at https://github.com/fredwillmore/coffee_test

Here's the **coffeescript** file that creates the component:

```
class ThingDoer extends HTMLElement
  # constructor: ->
  #   super()

customElements.define("thing-doer", ThingDoer);
```

This is what the **coffeescript** transpiles to:

```
ThingDoer = (function(superClass) {
    extend(ThingDoer, superClass);

    function ThingDoer() {
      return ThingDoer.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    return ThingDoer;

  })(HTMLElement);

customElements.define("thing-doer", ThingDoer);
```

**Errors:**

with no constructor defined, I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

same with  a constructor that just calls "super":

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'HTMLElement': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.

I tried a constructor that just calls `new HTMLElement`:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The compiled script isn’t suitable as the class has been compiled to an ES5-style class which is not compatible with Custom Elements API.

Instead, you can write a little bit of raw JavaScript to generate a real class, then augment more methods to it using the [CoffeeScript’s Prototypal Inheritance syntax](https://coffeescript.org/#prototypal-inheritance):

```coffee
ThingDoer = `class ThingDoer extends HTMLElement { constructor() { super(); this.initialize(); } }`

ThingDoer::initialize = ->
  @innerHTML = 'meow'

customElements.define "thing-doer", ThingDoer
```

If the above code works in development but not when precompiling assets for production, the reason for that may be that your JS compresser doesn’t support ES6 syntax. You can [fix your asset pipeline by using a more modern compressor](https://makandracards.com/makandra/61701-using-esnext-without-a-transpiler-with-the-rails-asset-pipeline) such as [terser-ruby](https://github.com/ahorek/terser-ruby) or don’t transpile it (define the class in `eval` instead).

```coffee
ThingDoer = eval '(class ThingDoer extends HTMLElement { constructor() { super(); this.initialize(); } })'

ThingDoer::initialize = ->
  @innerHTML = 'meow'

customElements.define "thing-doer", ThingDoer
```